# Having [FATAL] Data Transformation Engine Initialization failed

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter

Having this error when I try to start a transformation

```
[FATAL] Data Transformation Engine initialization failed: 
<Status> 
<severity>5</severity>
<Event error_code="309118" severity='Failure">
<description>Attempt to write [109144] to event file failed. stopping execution.-for more information see file:///opt/app/Informatica/powercenter_961_HF3/DataTransformation/CMReports/Init/Events.cme</description> 
<log_file>opt/app/Informatica/powercenter_961_HF3/DataTransformation/CMReports/Init/Events.cme </log file> <time>N/A</time> 
</Event> 
</Status>.
```

Answer (score 0):

Found out that it is due to that opt/app/informatica is taking all of the disk space. Freed some space and the transformation worked again.